# Multilanguage OpenCalais like system?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, multilingual, semantic-analysis, opencalais

I was very impressed with the OpenCalais system. It's (is/has) a web service where you send your text, they analyze it, then you are provided with a series of categorized (RDF enabled) tags that your document belongs to.

But - at the moment - English is the only supported language.

Do you know of similar systems that handle multilanguage documents? (I'm interested n Italian, but multi language is a plus, of course)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Apache Stanbol](http://stanbol.apache.org/) can analyze texts in many different languages. So far the following languages are supported (precision and recall values may vary according to the language):

- English,
- 中文 (Chinese),
- Español (Spanish),
- Русский (Russian),
- Português (Portuguese),
- Deutsch (German),
- **Italiano (Italian)**,
- Nederlands (Dutch),
- Svenska (Swedish),
- Dansk (Danish),
- العربية (Arabic),
- עברית (Hebrew),
- 日本語 (Japanese).

The analysis will return the discovered entities. The analysis output format can be:

- JSON-LD,
- RDF/XML,
- RDF/JSON,
- Turtles,
- N-TRIPLES.

Entities, or tagging, of texts can be further tailored according to the system configuration. Ideally any custom vocabulary can be plugged into the system.

There are a couple of demo end-points:

- http://dev.iks-project.eu:8080/enhancer
- http://dev.iks-project.eu:8081/enhancer

Not sure whether all the above languages are supported in the afore-mentioned end-points.

[RedLink GmbH](http://www.linkedin.com/company/redlink-gmbh) is going to provide cloud services based on Apache Stanbol and related software.

The [WordLift plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordlift/) for WordPress already provides text analysis within WordPress for **all the afore-mentioned languages** (currently in testing stage). You can try it out installing the plug-in in WordPress and submitting textual contents in the post body.

You can also subscribe and write to the [Apache Stanbol mailing list](http://stanbol.apache.org/development/index.html#mailing_lists) for specific requests or information.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCalais supports both French and Spanish metadata tagging for entities. The set of entities will be extended in future releases. See our online documentation at http://www.opencalais.com/documentation/calais-web-service-api